# Querying records that meet muliple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I’m trying to write a query and I’m struggling to figure out how to go about it. 
I have a suppliers table and a supplier parts table I want to write a query that lists suppliers that have specified related Parts in the supplier parts table. If a supplier doesn’t have all specified related parts then they should not be listed. 
At the moment I have written a very basic query that lists the supplier if they have a related supplier part that meets the criteria.

```
SELECT id ,name 
FROM 
efacdb.dbo.suppliers INNER JOIN [efacdb].[dbo].[spmatrix] ON 
id = spmsupp 
WHERE spmpart 
IN ('ALUM_5083', 'ALUM_6082')
```

I only want to show the supplier if they have both parts related.  Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery with counting distinct occurences:

```
select * from suppliers s
where 2 = (select count(distinct spmpart) from spmatrix 
           where id = spmsupp and spmpart in ('ALUM_5083', 'ALUM_6082'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you can modify your query to get what you want, just by using an aggregation:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM efacdb.dbo.suppliers INNER JOIN
     [efacdb].[dbo].[spmatrix] 
     ON id = spmsupp 
WHERE spmpart IN ('ALUM_5083', 'ALUM_6082')
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING MIN(spmpart) <> MAX(spmpart);
```

If you know there are no duplicates, then `having count(*) = 2` also solves the problem.